# Can you execute sqlite3 outside xbin directory?

Tags: sqlite

When sqlite3 is installed you can execute the binary e.g. via a terminal emulator.

If sqlite3 is not installed per default and you do not want to root the phone to install it, is there any possibility to use the binary outside the xbin directory?

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the binary available, you could upload it to your device and use it from there. Note, however, that this won't work from SDCards – but the following approach should do without rooting:

```
adb push sqlite /data/local/sqlite
adb shell "chmod 0755 /data/local/sqlite"
```

Then you can always invoke it using the full path, e.g. `/data/local/sqlite somedatabase.db`, from within a terminal app or `adb shell` session.